# Matplotlib BoxPlot Labels and Title

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, time-series

Thank you in advance for your help!

**I am trying to create a boxplot in matplotlib and I get an error when trying to add the labels.
This is the code that pulls an error:**

```
df_selected_station_D.boxplot(column='20 cm', by='Month',figsize=(15,5),grid=True, xlabel = 'x data');
```

**This is the error it causes:**

```
TypeError: boxplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xlabel'
```

**What does this error mean and why am I getting it? (Complete code and images below)**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


raw_data = pd.read_csv('all-deep-soil-temperatures.csv', index_col=1, parse_dates=True)
df_all_stations = raw_data.copy()

df_selected_station = df_all_stations[df_all_stations['Station'] == 'Minot']
df_selected_station.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace=True);
df_selected_station_D=df_selected_station.resample(rule='D').mean()
df_selected_station_D['Day'] = df_selected_station_D.index.dayofyear

mean=df_selected_station_D.groupby(by='Day').mean()
mean['Day']=mean.index


df_selected_station_D['Month'] = df_selected_station_D.index.month
df_selected_station_D.head()
```

[image]

```
df_selected_station_D.boxplot(column='20 cm', by='Month',figsize=(15,5),grid=True);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is not the same, but adding labels and modifying titles can be accomplished with the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
ax1 = df.boxplot(column=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], figsize=(15,5), grid=True)
ax1.set_title('test title')
ax1.set_xlabel('x data')
ax1.set_ylabel('y data')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will make sure to accept your answer when the time limit expires!